# Multiple Java threads and control over thread distribution across muliple cores

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, stream, platform-specific

When we have multiple core machines and with Java concurrency, multiple threads across multiple cores is possible. Also, we do have stream in Java which can help distribute the work.

However, how do we ensure that threads are properly distributed across the cores so that we make efficient use of the cores?

How does the thread distribution differ across windows and Linux operating systems? And how does it differ across Intel and AMD processors? Do we need to handle threads in specific ways for different OS and processors?

Comment: What makes you think they are not efficiently distributed?

Comment: I don't think there's any way to control thread affinity in Java. (I think "affinity" is what it's called when you designate certain threads to run on certain cores.)  You have to trust the optimizer to spot any such need.  I don't know if the JIT currently actually does this.  You might want to ask on the Open JDK list if there's any recourse available to you.

Comment: That's the job of the OS thread scheduler, not your job.

Comment: Short answer: you don’t. Long answer: write your own kernel. Distribution amongst cores is controlled by the context switcher in the kernel. It is worth noting that on Windows you can set thread priorities from task manager, there is likely a programmatic way of doing that, but it is usually a pretty manual process controlled by the user.

Comment: Some threading packages actually allow a programmer to do this though.  I think that's what he's asking for.  Not every system schedules threads 100% at random, a clever algorithm can actually find some speed ups using CPU thread affinity. @JBNizet

Comment: @Raedwald   Since Processor and OS may influence some of the work distribution and there could be several applications running, I am afraid all our threads could run on 1 or 2 cores even if there are 16 cores

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you would want to match the number of **computational** threads to the number of hardware threads.

This is the default behaviour of `ForkJoinPool`, configurable through other constructor or, for the common pool, the `java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism` system property. You may want to lower this if there is other computational intensive work happening on the system. The Stream API doesn't appear to specify behaviour (I may be wrong), but reasonable implementations would use the current `ForkJoinPool` (i.e. the pool of the current task is running in, or the common pool if running outside of any pool).

As ever, parallelism may make your program speed go down as well as up.

Scheduling threads is down to the platform, typically delegated to the operating system. Some JRE implementations in the past have moved Java threads between OS threads, but that's about handling I/O blocking.

Answer (score 1):

Java Thread uses the native thread facilities of the underlying OS. So, you have no control, within Java, over how the OS runs the Thread, apart from whatever values the Thread class allows you to pass to the OS. How Java and the OS handle those values depends on the OS and the Java implementation.

I don't get the impression you are an advanced systems programmer, so I suggest you let Java handle efficiency.

Comment: Thank you for the information!. I am trying to learn a lot more. It does not matter if I am not an advance systems programmer. I like to scale up to the need :-)

Comment: We may not control how OS runs the thread. If there is a way to let the OS consider how we prioritize our threads(of course, we already specify thread priorities) and how we want to execute in parallel on different cores, that is what I am trying to understand. This includes how the OS distributes the threads when it gets a lot of those.